# hadoop: defining map/reduce tasks properties

Tags: hadoop

I've tried to find a coherent explanation of how to set the following properties:

```
mapred.map.tasks
mapred.reduce.tasks
mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum
mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum
mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps
```

For a concise use case, I have 4 nodes, with 12 cores each with 2 hyperthreads (so cpuinfo shows 24), 64GB memory. I use the first node for both name node/job tracker and data node/task tracker. I don't execute jobs in parallel. For low memory settings, jobs failed on heap space, so my mapred.child.java.opts settings are now -Xmx3G -XX:+UseParallelGC. Using Hadoop 1.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mapred.map.tasks` - This property defines the number of map tasks to run for a job and is not usually configured by your job. This is usually defined by the input format, the number of files to be processed and the splittable properties of those files. In short you shouldn't need to set this property (I haven't in 4 years of using Hadoop).

`mapred.reduce.tasks` - This property controls the number of reducers to run for a given job. This is configured by the programmer during the job configuration phase - see [JobConf.setNumReduceTasks](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setNumReduceTasks%28int%29) or [Job.setNumReduceTasks](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#setNumReduceTasks%28int%29).

`mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` - This property is set in the conf/mapred-site.xml file and denotes the maximum number of concurrent map slots a given task tracker node can run. If you need to change this value, you'll need to restart the tasktracker service as it's only read at startup

`mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum` - As with the above property, this one defines the maximum number of concurent reducer tasks that can be run by a given task tracker.

`mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps` - This defines the ratio of map tasks that need to have completed before the reducer task phase can be started. This value is set by the programmer during the job configuration phase (you'll need to manually set this property as there is not convenience method like the first two). the value ranges between 0 and 1: 0 being start reducer tasks before any maps have completed (not advised), and 1 being don't start any reducer tasks until all the map tasks have finished for that job. The value is typically set to 0.8 - 0.99.